# Bootstrap with AngularJS: ng-disabled is not noticable with btn-xs (or btn-sm)

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Please consider the following [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/IMWJLVA6nmtGZlRSmv7w?p=preview).

I'm using this controller:

```
app.controller('myController', [
      '$scope',
      function($scope){

        $scope.isDisabled = true;

        $scope.ClickMe = function(text) {
          alert(text);
        };
}]);
```

And this HTML:

```
<body ng-app="ngApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
      <p>
        Is disabled:
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isDisabled"/>
      </p>
      <p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="isDisabled" ng-click="ClickMe('Save')">Save</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-disabled="isDisabled" ng-click="ClickMe('Cancel')">Cancel</button>
      </p>
      <p>
        <button class="btn-xs btn-primary" ng-disabled="isDisabled" ng-click="ClickMe('Save')">Save</button>
        <button class="btn-xs btn-danger" ng-disabled="isDisabled" ng-click="ClickMe('Cancel')">Cancel</button>
      </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Question**

As you can notice, there's no visible difference between disabled/enabled state for the buttons styled btn-xs. The normal btn buttons are fine.

The actual state itself does work however, as you can't click on the buttons when disabled.

Am I doing something wrong or is that just how btn-xs btn-sm works?
Is there an easy way to toggle disabled state in a way that is visible to the user?

Maybe a custom class based on btn-xs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to give the small buttons the 'btn' class.

Comment: I didn't know you still had to use btn, I thought btn-xs was instead of btn. Thanks!